# How to scrape multiple json pages with CrawlSpider?

Tags: scrapy

I have a json file that I want to scrape: https://www.website.com/api/list?limit=50&page=1

I can use 'scrapy.Spider' to crawl all the pages no problem, but if it's possible I prefer to do it with 'CrawlSpider'.

I tried to use:

```
    start_urls=['https://www.website.com']
    rules = (                                                                               
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/api/list\?.+page=\d+'), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    )
```

and (just to see if it's even getting the first page):

```
    start_urls=['https://www.website.com']
    rules = (                                                                               
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/api/list'), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    )
```

and none of them worked.

Is there a way to do it with 'CrawlSpider'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with [CrawlSpider](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/2.5.0/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py).
LinkExtractor used to process CrawlSpider Rules ->  can extract links only from html responses (not json api) from tags [`a` and `area`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/8284de5e7613c47e69d40d4f6a2a1dc846b50dd6/scrapy/linkextractors/lxmlhtml.py#L110)